# how to get syslog messages from Cisco firewall completely in delphi?

Tags: delphi, indy, cisco, syslog

I want to read syslog from UDP on port 514.
I am using delphi 2010. I put an IdUDPServer and set DefaultPort with 514 and BuffeSize with 1024.
this syslog is generated by Cisco firewall 5505.
I am sending ping to my firewall like this command. **Ping 192.168.1.100 -t**
when I run the kiwi (a software which is monitoring syslog messages) I get 2 message for each ping like this.

%ASA-6-302021: Teardown ICMP connection for faddr 192.168.1.4/1 gaddr 192.168.1.100/0 laddr 192.168.1.100/0
%ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 192.168.1.4/1 gaddr 192.168.1.100/0 laddr 192.168.1.100/0

but in my Listener I just get one message for each ping. like this
%ASA-6-302020: Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 192.168.1.4/1 gaddr 192.168.1.100/0 laddr 192.168.1.100/0

I don't know why I can't get the first message in my listener.
I wrote my code like this on OnRead event of the IdUDPServer

```
procedure TMyTestOnSyslog.Listener514UDPRead(
  AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; AData: TBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var S:string;
    i:Integer;
begin
  S:='';
  for i := 0 to High(AData) do
    S:=S+chr(Adata[i]);
  ...
end;
```

what should I do? :D

Comment: after I work around with my code and try to test. I get the 302021 error message in my list but there was no 302020 in this time! I think because these 2 message come in a same time the IdUDPServer can't read both. but I don't know what to do fix this :|

Comment: Try using `TIdSysLogServer` instead. It's a specialized component that listens on port 514 by default. It will trigger `OnSysLog` event every time a new message is received. The only thing you may have to do is set your Cisco firewall to forward SysLog messages to IP address of the machine where your application is running.

Comment: the problem is the TIdSysLogServer itself is inherited from TIdUDPServer. I tested the TIdSysLogServer and get same result. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am disappointed when one of when I called one of my friends and asked about this matter. he said better to not use Indy in delphi, because it is bugy. so I searched for the other components. there is an open source one. ICS(Internet Component Suite) which is working very well. you can get this open source for any delphi version or C++ Builder!

see this : http://www.overbyte.be/

in product part select ICS and you can download the latest version.
fortunately it has many component and it has TSysLogServer. it doesn't lose any packet of UDP.
it is true that UDP doesn't guarantee no loss for packets. but when I see other programs like kiwi and wiresharks get the packets properly I should know that the source of the problem in my program is the component.

so the answer for my question is: **DON'T USE INDY !!!**

I don't know Indy just in delphi have problems like this or in other languages is same. :|

Comment: Both Indy and ICS are open source, so the developer community can provide patches for bugs. Maybe the UDP problem has already been solved in a later version of Indy. My first action would be to update the library to check if the bug is still there, not dropping it.

Comment: Funny... as far as i remember Indy was created as opensource alternative to commercial ICS, and now people started to migrating back :-)